# Vertx Service Proxy Compilation error Cannot resolved to be a type

Tags: java, proxy, vert.x, vertx-verticle, vertx-eventbus

I am working with vertx service proxy. As I try to add all the required dependencies and package-info java file. I still get vertx compilation error cannot be resolved to a type. From tutorial I have learnt that it is a generated file but It does not generate.

The pom.xml is as below:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>io.vertx.starter</groupId>
<artifactId>vertx-start-project</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
<vertx.version>3.8.3</vertx.version>
<main.verticle>io.vertx.starter.MainVerticle</main.verticle>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
    <artifactId>vertx-stack-depchain</artifactId>
    <version>${vertx.version}</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
  <artifactId>vertx-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.12</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
  <artifactId>vertx-unit</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
    <artifactId>vertx-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
    <artifactId>vertx-web-templ-freemarker</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.rjeschke</groupId>
    <artifactId>txtmark</artifactId>
    <version>0.13</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
    <artifactId>vertx-jdbc-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
    <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
</dependency>   
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
    <artifactId>vertx-service-proxy</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
    <artifactId>vertx-codegen</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
  </dependencies>

 <build>
<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.5.1</version>
      <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>

        <annotationProcessors>
        <annotationProcessor>io.vertx.codegen.CodeGenProcessor</annotationProcessor>
        </annotationProcessors>
        <generatedSourcesDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/generated</generatedSourcesDirectory>
        <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-AoutputDirectory=${project.basedir}/src/main</arg>
        </compilerArgs>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <!-- tag::clean[] -->
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
      <configuration>
        <filesets>
          <fileset>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/generated</directory>
          </fileset>
        </filesets>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <!-- end::clean[] -->
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.2</version>
      <configuration>
        <skip>true</skip>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
</pluginManagement>

<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <transformers>
            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
              <manifestEntries>
                <Main-Class>io.vertx.core.Launcher</Main-Class>
                <Main-Verticle>${main.verticle}</Main-Verticle>
              </manifestEntries>
            </transformer>
            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
              <resource>META-INF/services/io.vertx.core.spi.VerticleFactory</resource>
            </transformer>
          </transformers>
          <artifactSet>
          </artifactSet>
          <outputFile>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-fat.jar</outputFile>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>

  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <mainClass>io.vertx.core.Launcher</mainClass>
      <arguments>
        <argument>run</argument>
        <argument>${main.verticle}</argument>
      </arguments>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

And the Database Service interface is as follows:

```
  @VertxGen
  @ProxyGen
  public interface WikiDatabaseService {

@Fluent
WikiDatabaseService fetchAllPages(Handler<AsyncResult<JsonArray>> resultHandler);

@Fluent
WikiDatabaseService fetchPage(String name, Handler<AsyncResult<JsonObject>> resultHandler);

@Fluent
WikiDatabaseService createPage(String title, String markdown, Handler<AsyncResult<Void>> resultHandler);

@Fluent
WikiDatabaseService savePage(int id, String markdown, Handler<AsyncResult<Void>> resultHandler);

@Fluent
WikiDatabaseService deletePage(int id, Handler<AsyncResult<Void>> resultHandler);

@GenIgnore
static WikiDatabaseService create(JDBCClient dbClient, HashMap <SqlQuery, String> sqlQueries, Handler<AsyncResult<WikiDatabaseService>> readyHandler) {
    return new WikiDatabaseServiceImpl(dbClient, sqlQueries, readyHandler);
}

@GenIgnore
static WikiDatabaseService createProxy(Vertx vertx, String address) {
return new WikiDatabaseServiceVertxEBProxy(vertx, address);
}

 }
```

and package-info is as follows:

```
 @ModuleGen(groupPackage = "io.vertx.starter.database", name = "starter-database")
 package io.vertx.starter.database;

 import io.vertx.codegen.annotations.ModuleGen;
```

Comment: Are you using Eclipse IDE or any other IDE that is not IntellIJ IDEA?

Comment: @NikolaS it's eclipse

Comment: @Jawad_Hassan_Soomro: Did my answer provide any help?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Eclipse as IDE for developing your Vert.X project which is using Service Proxies then you need to do few more things to be able to generate code:

1) Comment these lines in your *WikiDatabaseService* interface:

```
@GenIgnore
static WikiDatabaseService createProxy(Vertx vertx, String address) {
return new WikiDatabaseServiceVertxEBProxy(vertx, address);
}
```

2) Right click on your Vert.X project in Project Explorer, choose *Build Path*>*Configure Build Path*
2.1) Select **Source Tab** (make sure Java Build Path is selected in left side bar) 
2.2) Click on **Add Folder** 
2.3) Make sure that ***generated*** folder is checked under src/main/ 
2.4) Click OK and then *Apply*/*Apply and Close* 
3) In terminal/cmd (depending on OS you are using) inside of your Vert.X project folder execute following command: ***mvn clean package***  -> this command is necessary to execute as code generation needs to be performed for Proxy classes for code to be able to work properly.
4) Uncomment code in step 1) and `run mvn clean package` command again
5) Try running your code now by executing `java -jar ./target/name_of_project-fat.jar` (in your case it should be `java -jar ./target/vertx-start-project-fat.jar`) **ORR** `sh ./redeploy.sh` (**on Linux**)

Reason for this is that Eclipse, unlike IntellIJ IDEA, is not picking up generated folder under CLASSPATH as stated [here](https://vertx.io/docs/guide-for-java-devs/#_maven_configuration_changes) where it states:

> Note that the generated code is put in src/main/generated, which some
>   integrated development environments like IntelliJ IDEA will
>   automatically pick up on the classpath.

Hope it helps.